# UserCreationForm: текст подсказок по-русски

Tags: python, django

В UserCreationForm не полностью переводится текст подсказок. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: UserCreationForm]

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserOurRegistration(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

```
<div class="form-section">
    <form method="POST" id="reg_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn_register">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: `help_text` не переводиться в Django, пропишите его или в самом поле или в Meta.

Comment: А что именно добавить? ‘help-text’ и перевод? Что-то не совсем понимаю. Могли бы вы подробнее объяснить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте варианты описаные [здесь](https://overcoder.net/q/150581/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-helptext-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-django). Вам вероятно нужно будет переопределить список ошибок для вашей формы

Comment: Спасибо, но мне не нужно переопределять help_text. Мне лишь нужно, чтобы help_text из UserCreationForm показывался полностью на русском. Все переводится, кроме некоторых подсказок...

Comment: вы можете попробовать обернуть вашу форму в блок переводчик - читайте документацию))))https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/i18n/translation.html#trans-template-tag